# ConTeXt: "Chapter <n>" in header, language-dependent

Tags: header-footer, context

I'm currently in the process of moving from LaTeX to ConTeXt. Looks promising, in particular the huge amount of freedom in page layout design you gain with ConTeXt.

Of course, this freedom does have its cost -- loads of new setup commands to cope with... An it's surprisingly difficult to search for ConTeXt-related information 'cause "context" is such a common word that relevant hits often just get lost in an overwhelming flood of unrelated results which, by chance, also bear the word "context" in a different, well, context. ;)

One thing I'm currently struggling with is teaching ConTeXt to print the word "Chapter " in the header area, with "Chapter" being automatically replace by the corresponding word in the current document language. More precisely, I'd like to have "Chapter " on even and the chapter name on odd pages. I managed to get the chapter number  at the desired place using

```
\setupheadertexts%
[][chapter][{\somenamedheadnumber{chapter}{current}}][]
```

but I just can't figure out how to automatically print "Chapter " in a language-dependent manner.

Any help apprecieted!

Cheers --

Torsten

Comment: You can set language dependant texts with the `\translate`
 command, e.g. `\translate[en=Chapter,de=Kapitel,fr=Chapitre]`.

Comment: I see, thanks... But in ConTeXt, there are already built-in translations for words like "Chapter" -- isn't it possible to make use of those instead of providing your own translations?

Comment: I have posted an (unsatisfactory) answer.  I will ask this on the mailing list as well.

Comment: ConTeXt stores language dependent strings for `chapter` and `section` but it doesn’t create label texts for them.

Comment: Link to my crosspost: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088627.html

Comment: Wow... didn't expect this to be so complicated! Relying on implementation details does indeed not seem so future-proof. Henri, if you don't mind, I'll wait a little longer to see what other people might come up with before marking your answer as definite.

Comment: OT: Is there any particular reason that you are using `\somenamedheadnumber{chapter}{current}` instead of `chapternumber`?

Comment: Nope -- just copy & paste from some example I found. Glad to learn that `\chapternumber` will do, though -- I was starting to worry if all ConTeXt commands would have such lengthy names..

Comment: Hmm... `\chapternumber` confronts me with an `Undefined control sequence` error... `\namedheadnumber{chapter}` does work, but I still wonder if there is a shorter command available for displaying the current chapter/section/subsection... number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm absolutely sure there is a better way to access this, but for now this is the best I could get.

```
\def\chaptername{%
  \ctxlua{%
    context(languages.data.labels.texts.chapter.labels["\currentlanguage"])}}

\setupheadertexts%
  [\chaptername] [chapter]
  [{\somenamedheadnumber{chapter}{current}}] []

\starttext

\mainlanguage[de]

\startchapter[title=Knuth]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Zapf]
  \input Zapf
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Henri, since no further suggestions came in (not even on the mailing list you cross-posted on) I accept your answer. Thanks for your help!